# UITableview load default selected values with checkmark in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a method setting up value for table view for multi-selection row

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle options:(NSArray *)aOptions matchingArray:(NSArray *)matchArray xy:(CGPoint)point size:(CGSize)size isMultiple:(BOOL)isMultiple
{
isMultipleSelection=isMultiple;
float height = MIN(size.height, DROPDOWNVIEW_HEADER_HEIGHT+[aOptions count]*44);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, height);
if (self = [super initWithFrame:rect])
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.5, 2.5);
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;

    _kTitleText = [aTitle copy];
    _kDropDownOption = @[@"India",@"Swaziland",@"Africa",@"Australlia",@"Pakistan",@"Srilanka",@"Mexico",@"United Kingdom",@"United States",@"Portugal"];

    _kMatchingArray = @[@"United States",@"Swaziland"];
    finalarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for(int i = 0;i<[_kMatchingArray count];i++)
    {
        for(int j= 0;j<[_kDropDownOption count];j++)
        {
            if([[_kMatchingArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[_kDropDownOption objectAtIndex:j]])
            {

                NSLog(@"%d",j);
                NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j];
                [finalarray addObject:str];

            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"finalArray:%@",finalarray);
  //  NSLog(@"%@",_kMatchingArray);
    self.arryData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _kTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(DROPDOWNVIEW_SCREENINSET,
                                                               DROPDOWNVIEW_SCREENINSET + DROPDOWNVIEW_HEADER_HEIGHT,
                                                               rect.size.width - 2 * DROPDOWNVIEW_SCREENINSET,
                                                               rect.size.height - 2 * DROPDOWNVIEW_SCREENINSET - DROPDOWNVIEW_HEADER_HEIGHT - RADIUS)];
    _kTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.2];
    _kTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _kTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _kTableView.dataSource = self;
    _kTableView.delegate = self;
    [self addSubview:_kTableView];

    if (isMultipleSelection) {
        UIButton *btnDone=[UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnDone setFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x+182,rect.origin.y-45, 82, 31)];
        [btnDone setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnDone addTarget:self action:@selector(Click_Done) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:btnDone];
    }


}
return self;
   }
```

using this i have create a tableview fetching the values

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
           return [_kDropDownOption count];
      }
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cel lForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
static NSString *cellIdentity = @"DropDownViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentity];
cell = [[DropDownViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentity];

     NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
   // NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [finalarray addObject:indexPath.row];

UIImageView *imgarrow=[[UIImageView alloc]init ];
NSLog(@"aray:%@",self.arryData);
if([self.arryData containsObject:indexPath]){
    imgarrow.frame=CGRectMake(230,2, 27, 27);
    imgarrow.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_mark@2x.png"];
} else
    imgarrow.image=nil;

[cell addSubview:imgarrow];

cell.textLabel.text = [_kDropDownOption objectAtIndex:row] ;
return cell;
   }

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  if (isMultipleSelection) {
    if([self.arryData containsObject:indexPath]){
        [self.arryData removeObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        [self.arryData addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];

} else {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(DropDownListView:didSelectedIndex:)]) {
        [self.delegate DropDownListView:self didSelectedIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
    // dismiss self
    [self fadeOut];
}

 }
```

I have two array one have total records of the tableview and another one have initially selected values.I have compare the two arrays and get matching indexpath. My problem was how to set check mark image on matched values row?

Comment: Unable to understand what you want. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([_strProIDNS isEqualToString:strUNAssignNS])
        {
            tblViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
            tblViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: change as per your requirement i think it will works